# How to extract the following information using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the HTML source

```
<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Ownership: </label>Private</div>
<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Institute Type: </label> Affiliated College</div>
```

How can I extract only Private and Affiliated College from the following source. Also both information should be separately extracted into two different variable. The method should be scalable so that it can be used to extract all the information for similar large source code with above html repeating itself.

By scalable I mean to say

```
   college1<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Ownership: </label>Private</div>
<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Institute Type: </label> Affiliated College</div>
college2<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Ownership: </label>Private</div>
    <div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Institute Type: </label> Affiliated College</div>
```

so suppose I need to extract Private and Affiliated College for both or n such entities

Comment: are you asking how to get the actual text "Private" and "Affiliated"?

Comment: What is `college1` and `college2` here? Shouldn't they be in some tag?

Comment: college 1, college 2 is the name of the college about which the information is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the `<div>` tag which contains the text you want by using

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='clg-type clgAtt')
```

Since the first tag is for *Ownership* and second one is for *Institute Type*, you can assign them like this:

```
ownership, institute = soup.find_all('div', class_='clg-type clgAtt')
```

Now, if you print the contents of any one variable (`print(ownership.contents)`), you'll see this:

```
[<label class="label">Ownership: </label>, 'Private']
```

So, you can use `contents[1]` or `contents[-1]` to get the text you want, since it is located in the 1st index (or the last index) of `contents`.

Complete code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Ownership: </label>Private</div>
<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Institute Type: </label>Affiliated College</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

ownership, institute = [x.contents[1] for x in soup.find_all('div', class_='clg-type clgAtt')]
print(ownership, institute, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Private
Affiliated College
```

Comment: it is very helpful but how can I scale this for suppose 2 entities i.e.

college1<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Ownership: </label>Private</div>
<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Institute Type: </label>Affiliated College</div>
college2<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Ownership: </label>Private</div>
<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Institute Type: </label>Affiliated College</div>

Comment: Can you add that HTML in the question itself? It's hard to read that here. Also, it'll be confusing for others if I make changes in my code based on this comment.

Comment: ya fine I will add the new Html in the question itself

Comment: I'm guessing that each entity is located inside some tag. So, find and save those tags which have entities in them using `find_all()` and then use the code I've provided inside the loop. Just replace `soup` with the new variable in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help
Actually i am working on college mini project and I am just a newbie in data scraping. is there any way you can help me with the project as i am finding it difficult to extract some information. Or can you please refer me to good online course or website.

Comment: The best place to learn to use BeautifulSoup is the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 0):

The following method is destructive to the soup, but that can be fixed by copying the tags after finding them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Ownership: </label>Private</div>
<div class="clg-type clgAtt"><label class="label">Institute Type: </label> Affiliated College</div>'''

soup = bs(html,'lxml')
divs = soup.find_all('div')
text = []
for div in divs:
    div.label.extract()
    text.append(div.text)
print(text)
```

**Result**

```
['Private', ' Affiliated College']
```